# Help with a derivitive

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Im studying for my final in calculus and there is one derivative that I am having an issue with:

$$
1\over x(\ln x)^p
$$

The solution according to the book:

$$
-{p+\ln x\over x^2\ln x^{p+1}}
$$

What I am getting:

$$
-{p(\ln x)^{-2p-1} + 1\over{x^2(\ln x)^p}}
$$

My process:

$$
{1\over x(\ln x)^p} = {1\over x} \cdot {1\over (\ln x)^p}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
{\left({1\over x(\ln x)^p}\right)^\prime} & = -{1\over x}p(\ln x)^{-p-1}\left({1\over x}\right) + {1\over (\ln x)^p}\left({-1\over x^2}\right) \tag{Pruduct Rule} \\
& ={-p(\ln x)^{-p-1}\over x^2} - {1\over x^2 (\ln x)^p} \\
& ={-p(\ln x)^{-p-1}(\ln x)^p\over  x^2(\ln x)^p} - {1\over x^2 (\ln x)^p} \\
& =-{p(\ln x)^{-2p-1} + 1\over{x^2(\ln x)^p}}
\end{align}
$$

I feel like it is something really simple that I am missing so if someone would be kind enough to point out where I went wrong I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to type ln\space x.  Just type \ln x.  Then you see $\ln x$, and the spacing is automatic both on the left and right, as in things liks $a\ln b$.  And $\ln$ is not italicized. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\ln x)^{(-p-1)}(\ln x)^p=(\ln x)^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

$$ (\ln x)^{-p-1}(\ln x)^p \neq (\ln x)^{-2p-1}$$
$$ (\ln x)^{-p-1}(\ln x)^p = (\ln x)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the power rule: $\dfrac{d}{dx} x^\alpha = \alpha\cdot x^{\alpha - 1}$. Thus: $y = \left(x\cdot (Lnx)^p\right)^{-1} \to y ' = \dfrac{-1}{x^2\cdot (Lnx)^{2p}}\cdot \left(1\cdot (Lnx)^p + x\cdot p\cdot (Lnx)^{p-1}\cdot \dfrac{1}{x}\right) = \dfrac{(Lnx)^{p-1}\cdot (-Lnx - p)}{x^2\cdot (Lnx)^{2p}} = -\dfrac{p + Lnx}{x^2\cdot (Lnx)^{p+1}}$